# Is it possible to stream all Cloudwatch logs to S3 or files in EC2?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to be able to export and stream all the Cloudwatch log groups or atleast stream a list of 50 log groups to S3. I have seen patterns with lambda where you stream a particular log group. Is there a way to do this for all the log groups or atleast a specific list of log groups?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You can export logs from the required log groups to S3 directly using CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html
2. For real time processing of logs, you can define a subscription filter for the log groups using Lambda functions and store the data in S3 as required: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample

Comment: In the second option you suggested, will there be one lambda each for each Cloudwatch log group?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can create multiple subscription filters for different log groups to the same Lambda. Just one limit to keep in mind is the [20KB resource policy limit for Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html). This can be avoided by using wildcards.